# GestureDetector ontap does not work but ondouble tap works. flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Gesturedetector does not work if i use ontap but works if I change it to double tap.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Container(
  color: _color,
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      print('object');// does not work but if I change it to onDoubleTap it works.
    },
    child: SizedBox(
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.card_giftcard_outlined),
        onLongPress: () {},
        contentPadding:
            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
        // tileColor: Colors.green,
        title: Text(
          msg,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
        ),
        horizontalTitleGap: 32.0,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}
is this a bug in flutter or dart or am I missing something or doing something wrong

Comment: Try removing `onLongPress: () {},` from ListTile.

Comment: Holy shit, i didnt notice that at all, thank you it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `onLongPress:` in `ListTile` that's why it is not working. Chanage as:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: _color,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print(
              'object'); // does not work but if I change it to onDoubleTap it works.
        },
        child: SizedBox(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.card_giftcard_outlined),
            contentPadding:
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
            // tileColor: Colors.green,
            title: Text(
              msg,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
            ),
            horizontalTitleGap: 32.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

In case you need that `onTap` of `GestureDectector` you can utilize `onTap` of `ListTile` as follow:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: _color,
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: SizedBox(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.card_giftcard_outlined),
            onLongPress: () {},
            onTap: () {
              print("HELLO");
            },
            contentPadding:
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
            // tileColor: Colors.green,
            title: Text(
              msg,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
            ),
            horizontalTitleGap: 32.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: thankyou i forgot that i didnt notice the longpress.

Comment: Glad it helped hope to get a marked answer :)
Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Try putting Container instead of SizedBox and remove `onLongPress: () {},` and put it inside GestureDetector.

```
GestureDetector(
onTap: () {
  print('object');// does not work but if I change it to onDoubleTap it works.
},
onLongPress: () {

},
child: SizedBox(
  child: ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.card_giftcard_outlined),
    contentPadding:
        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
    // tileColor: Colors.green,
    title: Text(
      msg,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
    ),
    horizontalTitleGap: 32.0,
    ),
  ),
),
),
```

Comment: thankyou i forgot that i didnt notice the longpress.